# How to run a standalone program in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to run this program as a standalone program:

`module Main where main = putStrLn "Hello world!"`

so I typed in ghci:
`--make -o hello Main.hs`

but when I want to run it with `./hello` I get a parse error for `./`.
I tried also `ghc --make -o hello Main.hs` but then I get an "Variable not in scope: ghc" error.
Can somebody tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Solved: the command has to be run in the shell and ghc and Main.hs has to be in the same directory

Comment: If you get an error for `./`, then this is the shell that somehow does not understand what you are saying.

Comment: Do you run `ghc` by any chance in `ghci`?

Comment: yes, specifically in ghci-8.8.3

Comment: you should not call the compiler `ghc` in the `ghci` shell, but in your normal shell...

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: You do not compile the program in the `ghci` shell.

> so I typed in `ghci`: `--make -o hello Main.hs`

It looks like you are running this *in* `ghci` (based on the error message `Variable not in scope`). `ghci` is a Haskell shell, but you do not write commands to compile or run a program in the Haskell shell itself. You run these in a shell like `bash`, `sh`, `fish`, etc.

So you open a terminal window, and then you can `cd` to the correct directory where the `Main.hs` file is located, then you can write:

```
ghc --make -o hello Main.hs
```

or for a Windows system, you can add a `.exe` extension:

```
ghc --make -o hello.exe Main.hs
```

or as [@chi says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859578/how-to-run-a-standalone-program-in-haskell/61859624?noredirect=1#comment109412765_61859624), you can work with Haskell-stack:

```
stack ghc -- Main
```

Perhaps you need to add the directory of the executables to the `PATH` environment variable, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows).

and finally you can run this program, for example by writing `./hello` in the shell.

Comment: If I try this, I get an error message which says, that the command "ghc" couldn't be found

Comment: @Temeraire: then it looks like you did not install `ghc` properly. Where is the binary of ghci located? Normally this is located under `/usr/bin/ghc` on a Debian system.

Comment: I have a windows system, it is located in C:\User\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.3\bin

Comment: @Temeraire: and does that directory contain a `ghc` program?

Comment: @Temeraire: you can normally use `C:\User\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.3\bin\ghc --make -o hello.exe Main.hs` I think to execute a program in another directory.

Comment: `stack ghc -- Main` should produce `Main.exe` on windows, assuming stack works.

Comment: You *can* use GHCi as a shell, using something like turtle. GHCi also has a built-in command for running programs; I don't remember what it's called..